# Is it possible to keep the touch sensor on while the screen is off?

Tags: stock-android, touchscreen, power-options

I know that the touch sensor of a phone's screen requires power to operate. So, my question is that, is there any way to keep the touch sensor *on* while the screen is *off* in Android OS?

Comment: I think yes but I'm not 100% sure. Thing is I remember some old phone had thisbor similar thing because developer tried to make double tap to wake as LG phones have, but it had resulted in a huge battery drain and wasn't finished (I can't remember what phone it was, if I do I will post here). Anyway you would need to make custom kernel, and maybe even play with drivers. Why do you need this?

Comment: Actually, I am trying to make an Android app, which can respond to gestures even when the screen is off, for faster access.

Comment: Is that possible by acquiring **partial wake lock**?

Comment: I'm not sure but it will probably make battery drain because cpu won't be in doze or deep sleep, maybe if you use device sensors but not every device has double tap sensor and it doesn't allow much to do with it. Ask this on xda or stack owerflow because they deal with development